# Warning: socket_bind()

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to create a script that I read data on a socket.
I wrote this code:

```
<?php
    $ip='192.168.0.52';
    $port=9000;
    sleep(5);

    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
    socket_bind($sock, $ip, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');

    //this is where the reading loop should go.
    while(1){
        echo socket_read($sock,1024);
    }

    socket_close($sock);
?>
```

if I run the code and transmit data on the socket before 5 seconds elapse, everything works perfectly (you will see all messages in the browser)
If you wait more than 5 seconds or comment this line: sleep(5);
I read on the browser the following error:

> Warning: socket_bind(): in C:\xampp\htdocs\socket\index.php on line 7
>   Could not bind to address

How do I run this script without the use of sleep(5);
Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense...how can it work fine before the 5 seconds elapse if the socket isn't opened until _after_ the 5 seconds elapse?

Comment: then how should I do?

Comment: Print this in your die message: `socket_strerror(socket_last_error())`